# html2pdf save file to backend

Tags: pdf-generation, jspdf, html2pdf, xhtml2pdf

I'm using vue-html2pdf to generate a report which is working fine to output the report and save file in the browser
But
I also want to save the file to the server also, I've been looking into exporting the generated file as a string and posting it but can't see any library for converting html to a pdf that supports this.

I would look into generating the pdf server side to begin with but I have html charts which would be difficult to reproduce server side

Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: [Grin Zhou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16597537) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68660692) saying "You can do something at @hasDownloaded event [https://github.com/kempsteven/vue-html2pdf](https://github.com/kempsteven/vue-html2pdf)"